# I didn't quite understand the use of the .user.ini and what is the difference between the one placed in root and the one located in pub

Tags: magento2.4, pub, memory-limit, settings

I just finished installing and updating magento2 now I have a doubt about this type of file.

**.user.ini**

```
memory_limit = 2G
max_execution_time = 18000
session.auto_start = off
suhosin.session.cryptua = off
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & E_NOTICE & E_STRICT
```

to optimize my site should I change the following parameters?

```
memory_limit = 756M
```

Comment: I think default value is 756M and both file serve the same purpose just like .htaccess and index.php. If you are running project from pub, it will take values from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the file name should be **.user.ini**
and it will work from root dir.

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong, is a .user.ini

Comment: Okay, Hope it will work for you.